# DrilledDown graphs not working in latest highchart.js

Tags: highcharts, drilldown

I am using two level drill down graph in my web page.

I updated highchart.js to latest 3.0.9 version from  2.1.6  i am getting en error in drill down graph.
When ever i click on bar to get the second level of drill down i get following error.

> TypeError: animOptions is undefined

Can any one help em to find out why its not working.

Regards
Virendra Agrawal

Comment: can you try o reproduce the issue in a jsfiddle.

Comment: i could not reproduce is in jsfiddle as drill down there is using two extra js file one is Data.js and second is drilldown.js in earlier versions these were not in use.

Comment: Why you cannot attach? You can set it in header as other js files.